# How to reverse the order of rows

Tags: vba, excel

I try to write a macro that would reverse order of rows in my Excel worksheet, but unfortunately I fail. I don not know even how to start. I would be very grateful for any help or hints on how to do it.

Comment: insert a column, fill with **1,2,3,4** etc, down to the end of the rows you want reversed. Then select your data, including the column you just added, and sort in reverse (Largest to Smallest). Use Macro Recorder to see the code if you need to do it multiple times

Comment: Show your fail code ..

Comment: Step 1: Add the rows to an array variable while iterating from Rows.Count to 1.  Step 2: Write the array out on the worksheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select your rows and run this macro:

```
Sub ReverseList()
    Dim firstRowNum, lastRowNum, thisRowNum, lowerRowNum, length, count As Integer
    Dim showStr As String
    Dim thisCell, lowerCell As Range
    With Selection
        firstRowNum = .Cells(1).Row
        lastRowNum = .Cells(.Cells.count).Row
    End With
    showStr = "Going to reverse rows " & firstRowNum & " through " & lastRowNum
    MsgBox showStr

    showStr = ""
    count = 0
    length = (lastRowNum - firstRowNum) / 2
    For thisRowNum = firstRowNum To firstRowNum + length Step 1
        count = count + 1
        lowerRowNum = (lastRowNum - count) + 1
        Set thisCell = Cells(thisRowNum, 1)
        If thisRowNum <> lowerRowNum Then
            thisCell.Select
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cut
            Cells(lowerRowNum, 1).EntireRow.Select
            Selection.Insert
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cut
            Cells(thisRowNum, 1).Select
            Selection.Insert
        End If
        showStr = showStr & "Row " & thisRowNum & " swapped with " & lowerRowNum & vbNewLine
    Next
    MsgBox showStr
End Sub
```

Comment out the MsgBox if you don't like notifications.

Answer (score 1):

I simplified Wallys code a little and changed it, so that it has the row numbers as input parameters:

```
Sub ReverseList(firstRowNum As Integer, lastRowNum As Integer)

  Dim upperRowNum, lowerRowNum, length As Integer

  length = (lastRowNum - firstRowNum - 2) / 2
  For upperRowNum = firstRowNum To firstRowNum + length Step 1
    lowerRowNum = lastRowNum - upperRowNum + firstRowNum

    Cells(upperRowNum, 1).EntireRow.Cut
    Cells(lowerRowNum, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    Cells(lowerRowNum, 1).EntireRow.Cut
    Cells(upperRowNum, 1).EntireRow.Insert
  Next
End Sub
```

Tobi

Answer (score 0):

I extended Tobag's answer with a Range parameter, and making all arguments optional:

```
Sub ReverseRows(Optional rng As range = Nothing, Optional firstRowNum As Long = 1, Optional lastRowNum As Long = -1)

    Dim i, firstRowIndex, lastRowIndex As Integer
    
    ' Set default values for dynamic parameters
    If rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If lastRowNum = -1 Then lastRowNum = rng.Rows.Count
    
    If firstRowNum <> 1 Then
        ' On each loop, cut the last row and insert it before row 1, 2, 3, and so on
        lastRowIndex = lastRowNum
        For i = firstRowNum To lastRowNum - 1 Step 1
            firstRowIndex = i
            rng.Rows(lastRowIndex).EntireRow.Cut
            rng.Rows(firstRowIndex).EntireRow.Insert
        Next
    Else
        ' Same as above, except handle different Insert behavior.
        ' When inserting to row 1, the insertion goes above/outside rng,
        ' thus the confusingly different indices.
        firstRowIndex = firstRowNum
        For i = firstRowNum To lastRowNum - 1 Step 1
            lastRowIndex = lastRowNum - i + 1
            rng.Rows(lastRowIndex).EntireRow.Cut
            rng.Rows(firstRowIndex).EntireRow.Insert
        Next
    End If
  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was working with a table and wanted to only reverse the rows within that table, not the whole worksheet.

Due to an issue with odd/even row counts I changed it a bit so it works consistently. -1 instead of -2 and added an If.

```
Dim firstRowNum As Integer, lastRowNum As Integer
    firstRowNum = tbl.ListRows(1).Index
    lastRowNum = tbl.ListRows.Count
    Debug.Print "Going to reverse rows " & firstRowNum & " through " & lastRowNum
    Dim upperRowNum, lowerRowNum, length As Integer
    
    length = (lastRowNum - firstRowNum - 1) / 2 ' minus 1 instead of 2!! with the If statement below it works for odd and even row counts.
    For upperRowNum = firstRowNum To firstRowNum + length Step 1
        lowerRowNum = lastRowNum - upperRowNum + firstRowNum
        If upperRowNum <> lowerRowNum Then
            tbl.ListRows(upperRowNum).Range.Cut
            tbl.ListRows(lowerRowNum).Range.Insert
            tbl.ListRows(lowerRowNum).Range.Cut
            tbl.ListRows(upperRowNum).Range.Insert
        End If
    Next
```

Thanks everybody!